# When a feat refers to dealing your unarmed strike damage, does that include modifiers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, combat, monk

Multiple style feats, such as; [Djinni spin](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#djinni-spin), [Efreeti touch](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#efreeti-touch), [Marid coldsnap](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#marid-coldsnap), and [Shaitan earthblast](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#shaitan-earthblast), all say to deal 'unarmed strike damage' as part of their effect. Does that include modifiers to your unarmed strike damage, and if so, are their restrictions to which ones?

For example: If a monk of 10th level used [Dragon Roar](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#dragon-roar), would it include his strength bonus, or just do his unarmed strike damage of 1d10? If it did include his strength bonus, would it include the increase from [Dragon Ferocity](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#dragon-ferocity)? If he were under the effects of a [Magic Weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/magicWeapon.html#magic-weapon-greater) spell, would the +1 be included? If he were wearing an Amulet of Mighty Fist that made all of his attacks Axiomatic, would he add the +2d6 lawful damage? Are there modifiers I've not listed that would be added in addition to the 1d10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an official answer, but based on various threads there seems to be consensus (these 3 I found to be most helpful):

[Dragon Roar Clarification- Paizo Forum](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2o8ms?Dragon-Roar-clarification)

[Unarmed Strike Damage in Dragon Roar- Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/778er3/unarmed_strike_damage_in_dragon_roar/)

[Unarmed Strike Damage and Dragon Roar- GiantITP](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?523014-Unarmed-strike-damage-and-Dragon-roar)

If the rules text for a particular bonus says it increases "unarmed strike damage rolls" then it does apply. If it says "applies to an attack you make" then it does not apply. It seems like strength bonus should apply, including the dragon ferocity multiplier. Magic Weapon should work in this case.

It seems like Axiomatic would not work, since it is explicitly enhancing the weapon and not your unarmed strike damage. The same would be for Flaming or other properties.

Looking at Domain Strike, which is also from the book "Ultimate Combat", this seems indicate the intent was that unarmed strike damage is what you normally roll for unarmed attacks.

> Domain Strike (Combat)
>
> If you make a
> successful unarmed strike against an opponent, in addition to dealing
> your unarmed strike damage, you can use a swift action to deliver the
> effects of the chosen granted power to that opponent.